# In what category can we put X/Y or X:Y in Prolog

Tags: syntax, prolog, nomenclature

if I use something like this in Prolog

```
test(X/Y).
```

or

```
test(X:Y).
```

So `X:Y` and `X/Y` are considered as a variable, or as a string?

In what category we can put it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `X/Y`and `X:Y` are *compound terms*. Try:

```
?- functor(X/Y, Functor, Arity).
Functor =  (/),
Arity = 2.

?- X/Y =.. [Functor| Arguments].
Functor =  (/),
Arguments = [X, Y].

?- functor(X:Y, Functor, Arity).
Functor =  (:),
Arity = 2.

?- X:Y =.. [Functor| Arguments].
Functor =  (:),
Arguments = [X, Y].
```

Both `/` and `:` are standard *infix* operators:

```
?- current_op(Priority, Type, /).
Priority = 400,
Type = yfx.

?- current_op(Priority, Type, :).
Priority = 600,
Type = xfy.
```

The type `yfx` means that the operator is *left-assotiative*:

```
?- write_canonical(x/y/z).
/(/(x,y),z)
true.
```

While the type `xfy` means that the operator is *right-assotiative*:

```
?- write_canonical(x:y:z).
:(x,:(y,z))
true.
```